# Should I use static or instance functions to populate my object from a database?

Tags: c#, object, design-patterns, mvvm

I know this may be purely a design preference, but from your perspective:

1. Should my functions that retrieve items from the database be static or instance based?
2. What is generally the most preferred method? (And most common)
3. What are the Pros/Cons of each method?

I have an class which has 3 properties: (No constructor for the object)

- ObjectId - string
- Name - string
- Count - int

**Instance Based Example**

```
    public async void Get(string objectId) {
        // Gets specific item from "Tag" table
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Tag");
        ParseObject tagObject = await query.GetAsync(objectId);
        this.ObjectId = tagObject.ObjectId;
        this.Name = tagObject.Get<string>("name");
        this.Count = tagObject.Get<int>("count");
    }
```

Setting my object would be done like so:

```
    Tag myTag = new Tag();
    await myTag.Get("123456");
    // Properties are set and ready to work with
```

**Static Example**

```
    public static async Task<Tag> Get(string objectId) {
        Tag toReturnTag = new Tag();
        // Gets specific item from "Tag" table
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Tag");
        ParseObject tagObject = await query.GetAsync(objectId);
        toReturnTag.ObjectId = tagObject.ObjectId;
        toReturnTag.Name = tagObject.Get<string>("name");
        toReturnTag.Count = tagObject.Get<int>("count");
        return toReturnTag;
    }
```

And would be set as such:

```
    Tag myTag = await Tag.Get("123456");
```

Comment: Instance methods are much easier to mock for testing.

Comment: And this question may be a better fit for [programmers.se] - you might like to take a look over there (read their help first to make sure you're on-topic).

Comment: So for the sole reason of testing use an instance method to populate the properties from the database? I looked over there, but people didn't seem particularly responsive (not as popular, I guess). I figured some experienced mobile developers might have some insight on how to implement MVVM with a cloud DB.

Comment: For testing, and possibly inheritance. I am neither a mobile dev nor particularly experienced with MVVM; it was just one consideration that occurs to me.

Comment: This seems overly broad and subjective.

Comment: MVVM is designed for testability.  Statics promote tight coupling that complicates unit testing.  So why do one if you do the other?

Comment: If I use an instance method to retrieve the object it then in my ViewModel, I could potentially call "Get()" on an already instantiated method overwriting it. I want to prevent developers (myself included) from calling a function they're not supposed to.

Comment: And Peter, how could I transform this question into something more direct and less subjective? Instead of just downvoting my post, how about you provide some guidance? If you're not going to contribute something useful, don't contribute at all (effort counts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an explicitly, definitively better way of doing this. This is the kind of thing that, to me, depends on how you best want to associate responsibilities with the objects in your application. As it stands, both of your functions are more or less the same.

Logically, though, do you want "accessing the database" to be something that each Tag object is responsible for? Should they have knowledge of the database, and, in a greater sense, about anything outside themselves? Or should they just be constructed with the all the information they (seem to) need, and not worry about communication?

In your case, it doesn't seem like you accomplish anything from allowing your objects to take on database-accessing responsibility, so it seems to me like you're better off restricting their concerns in favor of the static option. (If you have to choose between those only those two, I mean. I think you could do just as well with a non-static method in your ViewModel which constructs and returns a Tag object. Mostly my feeling here is that Tags should try to restrict their concerns, not static vs. instance.)

Also, in the static case, why no constructor? You're setting all Tag object's properties before it's returned, so unless you have some need to be able to construct a Tag object with some or all of its properties as null, why not have one?

Edit: A few people have pointed out, reasonably, that static methods tend to make unit testing harder. I agree with that in principle, but I think he'd be more okay in this case:

1. There's not any state being stored or modified by the method. What comes out is the Tag object, and you can test that regardless of whether it came from an instance or static.
2. It relies on an external data call (GetQuery) that would need to be mocked anyway.

Without knowing enough about ParseObject.GetQuery (I think this might be Xamarin?), though, I'm not really sure whether a static, or this specific construction, would make it more difficult to mock the data source.

Comment: I do have a constructor, "Tag(string name){}", I was just leaving it out for simplicity purposes. I also have a private constructor for creating the objects to be returned by the static functions. Thanks for the response, it helped me make sense of it all. Question though: What do you think of having a base class which contains the GetAsParseObject and GetAsClass functions for each class? I could iterate through each of the properties recursively and create a generic "retrieve from the database" method. Any ideas/feedback before I spend the time trying to put something like that together?

Comment: @LeviFuller In regards to the base class (which I'm assuming will be abstract), I guess the main question is whether creating a class implementation for each database you'd like to access will end up leading to a cleaner, more testable/debuggable design? This is as opposed to a method that takes the specifics necessary for access and structures a more generic query from there. Are your databases/queries that different as to have little to no code duplication between all them?

Comment: @LeviFuller I know that's probably not the kind of answer you're looking for, but I've found the wrinkle of all this science is that it's often more art than science - design patterns are great, but I've found they're rarely objectively better unless you've got a textbook use case.

Comment: I want people to read the code of this app and say "It's beautiful". I'm still learning and this app is something I really want to show case my skills with. I still have lots to learn on my own. Programming is a complicated art, that's for sure and you're helping me understand the problem so I can learn and create my masterpiece, so I thank you very much for your time sir!

Comment: @LeviFuller Best of luck. Believe me that I'm nowhere close to beautiful code either, and I'm not sure whether I'll ever get there. It's a great goal, but keep in mind a saying I've heard before: the perfect is the enemy of the good. Don't let the urge to write perfect code stop you from getting the practice you need to get better.

Comment: I didn't find a message button anywhere, but would it be cool if we chatted via email so I could get some input? I don't really have access to any other developers so a second opinion from someone more experienced could help me out SOOOO much. I'm very new to code design. Feel free to shoot me an email. Levi.Fuller@Hotmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64078/discussion-between-levi-fuller-and-furkle).